# Set wallpaper on primary/secondary monitor only

Tags: c#, windows, wallpaper, multiscreen

Good day everyone.

I know how to set a wallpaper declaring

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern int SystemParametersInfo(int uAction, int uParam, string lpvParam, int fuWinIni);
```

and then using

```
SystemParametersInfo(0x0014, 0, file, 0x01 | 0x02);
```

but this sets the wallpaper, the same wallpaper on all the screens.

Is there any way to select which screen I want to update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sueggest you to read [that article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=25003), to understand how the background works with double monitor.
You not need to put 2 image in 2 diffente monitors but you need to create one that contains both images and put as backgroud.

An extract of the article linked:

> The trick is to set your wallpaper to “tile” rather than “center” or
>   “stretch”. When the window manager draws a tiled bitmap, it places the
>   tiles so that the upper left corner of the primary monitor exactly
>   coincides with the top left corner of a tile. The remaining tiles are
>   then arranged around that anchor tile.

Comment: This is nice. Thanks.

Comment: So this basically means you need to create a grid with the monitors exactly placed as how the monitors are ordered in the display settings in Windows... Is there a plugin for this?